# Creating a foreign key on an empty MySQL InnoDB table takes a very long time

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, alter-table

I have created a table called `asset_versions`:

```
CREATE TABLE "asset_versions" (
  "asset_id" int NOT NULL,
  "version" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  "created_at" datetime NOT NULL,
  "production_grade" tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("asset_id","version")
);
```

Now i want to “connect” the `asset_id` field to the `assets` table’s `id` (the primary key) field with a foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE asset_versions ADD CONSTRAINT asset_versions_asset_id_fk FOREIGN KEY(asset_id) REFERENCES assets(id);
```

The `assets` table is really small, currently contains 20 lines.

However, running the `ALTER TABLE` query still takes a lot of time, while my database is essentially unreachable: it’s now running for 20 minutes.

I’m using MySQL 8.0.25. The MySQL server is replicating everything via binlog, if that might be a concern.

Setting `unique_checks` and `foreign_key_checks` to `0` doesn’t help. I can kill the process which makes the DB accessible again, but this way the foreign key is (obviously) not created.

What else can i do to have this foreign key created without rendering my database unusable?

Comment: the problem is that mysql has to check every row if it violates the constraint, sothat will take time as it is a one time thing let it run, you can always run a replica for selects

Comment: Yes, that’s why i mention that the table i create the foreign key constraint on is completely empty, and even the referenced table is only 20 records long.

Comment: restart the server it seems the is something blocking it, but look first in the error log maybe there are hings zo abetter cofiguration